# If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, is the set $\{\delta\in\mathbb{R}:0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\}$ always an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Here's an interesting problem I stumbled upon while I was pondering on the $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ definition of a limit:

> Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ ($f$ is a real function). Fix some $\varepsilon>0$ and let $S_\varepsilon$ be the set
> $$\{\delta\in\mathbb{R}:|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\text{ is true for every $x\in\text{dom}[f]$ satisfying }0<|x-a|<\delta\}$$
> Does $S_\varepsilon$ always contain an interval? If so, can we do better and conclude that $S_\varepsilon$ **is** an interval that is either $(0,b)$, $(0,b]$, or $(0,\infty)$ for some $b>0$?

I’m pretty sure the answer to the first question is yes. Here's my argument:

> If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, then $S_\varepsilon$ is not empty because
> the $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ definition of a limit implies that there is
> a $\delta>0$ such that
>
> $$|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\text{ is true for every }x\in\text{dom}[f]\text{ satisfying } 0<|x-a|<\delta$$
>
> If we then fix any $\delta_1\in S_\varepsilon$, we can infer that every
> $s\in(0,\delta_1)$ will be an element of $S_\varepsilon$, since
>
> \begin{align}
> x\in\text{dom}[f]\text{ and }0<|x-a|<s\text{ and }s<\delta_1 &\implies x\in\text{dom}[f]\text{ and }0<|x-a|<\delta_1\\
> &\implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon
> \end{align}
> It follows $(0,\delta_1)\subseteq S_\varepsilon$, so $S_\varepsilon$
> contains an interval.

Does this argument work? If so, is the stronger claim mentioned in the problem statement also demonstrably true? After spending some time visualizing the $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ definition for constant functions and functions which are bounded/unbounded at the endpoints of their domain, I suspect that the answer is yes. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your claim holds and is primarily because if some $\delta$ works for an $\epsilon $ then a smaller $\delta$ also works for the same $\epsilon $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have the gist of it, but you might be bogged down by some unnecessarily complicated notation. How about this:

Let $\delta > 0$ be such that for any $x$ that satisfies the equation
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\left| x - a \right| < \delta,
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\left|f(x) -L  \right| < \varepsilon
\end{equation}

Let $0<\delta' < \delta$, if $\left| x- a \right| < \delta'$, then, since $\delta' < \delta$, we have $\left| x -a \right| < \delta' < \delta$ i.e. $x$ satisfies equation (1). This implies that equation (2) also holds.

In particular, this implies that if $\delta > 0$ is in $S_\varepsilon$, then $\left(0, \delta \right) \subset S_\varepsilon$. EDIT: Call this *Fact 1*.

EDIT: *$S_\varepsilon$ is an interval*:

Ether $S_\varepsilon$ has a supremum or not. If the supremum $s$ exists, then by *Fact 1* we have that $S_\varepsilon$ is either $(0, s)$ or $(0, s]$.

If $S_\varepsilon$ does not have a supremum, for any $M > 0$ there is an element $\delta > M$ in $S_\varepsilon$. Hence, by *Fact 1*, the set $S_\varepsilon$ contains the interval $(0, M)$ for arbitrarly large $M$'s. Thus $S_\varepsilon = (0,\infty)$.

Comment: The question is not that simple. I hope Alann Rosas realizes this too. What you have showed  is that the interval $(0,\delta=\delta(\epsilon))\subseteq S_{\epsilon}$. That is correct and your argument is correct. But this is not enough to prove that $S_{\epsilon}$ is an interval. One needs to show that there is an interval $I(\epsilon)$ such that $I(\epsilon)\subseteq S_{\epsilon}$ and $S_{\epsilon}\subseteq I(\epsilon)$. Can you show - for instance -that $S_{\epsilon} \subseteq (0,\delta=\delta(\epsilon))$ ?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering Matias! This is much more legible than my symbolic mess :P . That said, I don’t understand how you inferred that $S_\varepsilon$ is an interval from the fact that $(0, \delta)$ is a subset of $S_\varepsilon$. Could you be kind enough to explain your reasoning?

Comment: @Medo I have showed that if $a \in S_\varepsilon$ then $(0, a) \subset S_\varepsilon$. (This is way stronger than the fact that $S_\varepsilon$ merely contains an interval) The fact that $S_\varepsilon$ is an interval is an easy corollary.

Comment: @Alann Rosas Please read my second counterexample in the answer.

Comment: @Medo $S_\varepsilon$ is supposed to be a set of deltas not a set of $x$s

Comment: I don't see any problems with this answer as some comments seem to indicate. We have $S_{\epsilon} =(0, \sup S_{\epsilon}) $ or $S_{\epsilon} =(0, \sup S_{\epsilon}] $ where $\sup S_{\epsilon} $ may be $\infty$ if $S_{\epsilon} $ is unbounded. +1

Comment: @AlannRosas Edited the answer so that it details the last step.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä I see it now. Thank you so much!